# JPA Hibernate one to many batch insert

Tags: hibernate, jpa

conside this scenario:

```
    class Parent {
     private Integer id;
     private String name;
     @oneToMany(mappedBy="father")
     private List<Child> children;
     ... ...
    }

    class Child {
     private Integer id;
     private String name;
     @ManyToOne (optional="false")
     @JoinColumn(name="id")
     private Parent father;
     ........
}


Class MyParentService{

     public Parent parentService(List<Child> childList){
        em.getTransaction.begin();
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.setChildren(childList);
        em.persist(parent);
        em.getTransaction.commit();
   }
}
```

I will get an Exception of `org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient`

because the attribute father is "optional=false"

so I have to replace `parent.setChildren(childList);` and do a loop like this in parentService() :

```
for(Child c: childList){
 c.setFather(parent.getId());
 parent.getChildrent().add(c);
}
```

is this correct? is there a better way to do without looping childList again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with Hibernate, it's your responsibility to maintain consistent state of both sides of bidirectional relationship. Moreover, when persisting a relationship, Hibernate looks at the owning side (the side without `mappedBy`), so you code wouldn't be correct even without `optional=false`.

You can use the following approach to ensure consistensy:

```
class Parent {
    ...
    public void addChild(Child c) {
        children.add(c);
        c.setParent(this);
    }
}

public Parent parentService(List<Child> childList) {
    ...
    for (Child c: childList) {
        parent.addChild(c);
    }
    ...
}
```

In this case visibility of `setChildren()` can be restricted to avoid erroneous calls.

Aslo, it looks strange that you don't have cascading and don't persist children inside the same transaction with the parent.

Comment: thanks! I added cascade = {CascadeType.ALL} to both side. and I don't understand what do you mean with "looks strange that you don't persist children inside the same transaction with the parent." isn't when I persist the parent it will automatically persist him and all elements of his collection?? (children)

Comment: Elements of collection are persisted automatically only if you configured cascading, so without `cascade` it looked strange.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's good thing to do - e.g. in unit tests you may not use hibernate which automagically could set "father", but code should still work.